# onclick display <div> which is written after <button> (not all div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need specific `jquery` or `js` function to display `onclick`:

```
<div id="resultTab">
  <input id="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info"/>
  <div id="help">Table with data</div>
  <input id="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info"/>
  <div id="help">Table with data</div>
  <input id="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info"/>
  <div id="help">Table with data</div>
</div>
```

It can be repeated 50-100 times.
So when I click button it has to show only `<div>` which is written after that `<button>` not all `<div>`s

**Note:** all button and div's created by jquery so I can't give specific id to use in function.

Please help me to solve this problem. I'm totally stack, if its possible I want to display that `<div>` in the middle of page like popup window.

**UPDATE:** The function is working, but in this [situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF6Kb.png) its not working, what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the same ID everywhere, ID need to be uniqe. I changed your ID's to Class

```js
$('input.help_button').click(function () {
  $(this).next(".help").toggle()
})
```

```css
.help { display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info">
<div class="help">Table with data</div>
<input class="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info">
<div class="help">Table with data</div>
<input class="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info">
<div class="help">Table with data</div>
```

Comment: Can you add close function also please!

Comment: Now it will open and close the next div after a button click

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working, but I have one more problem please look at the picture, and help me to solve my last problem, Thanks

Comment: Please describe the problem a bit more

Comment: button and div is inside the td , and I want to display div with info in the middle of page, now when i click the button its not working...

Comment: Its not really clear what is wrong, Does nothing happen when you press the button or what is it?.

Comment: Nothing happens onclick

Comment: The reason for this can be many, the best help you can provide me is the post the html code for your entire table. Then i can troubleshoot the code

Comment: @Abdulin, your fiddle is wrong, corrected it. Check it https://jsfiddle.net/pkwxh726/2/. It seems that it works.

Comment: @Abdulin, also please check your console for errors. See if there is something. And also check that your included the jQuery library in your code.

Comment: Can you send me full html page code for this please, I want to check where im doing mistake. Thanks! abdu2016manila@gmail.com

Comment: We cant send you a full html page, since we dont know where your mistake is and we dont know your entire code so it would be hard to repreduce.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Can you check this code: http://jsfiddle.net/9z2ag/346/

When i click the button its opening all divs, I want to open just next div which is written after button, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
 $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `toggle()`, you can hide and show the div

```js
$('input.help_button').click(function () {
  $(this).next(".help").toggle()
})
```

```css
.help { display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info">
<div class="help">Table with data</div>
<input class="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info">
<div class="help">Table with data</div>
<input class="help_button" type="button" value="Full Info">
<div class="help">Table with data</div>
```

Comment: did you copy my answer`? funny how our code is 100% the same

Comment: brother when i post my answer you have edited your answer and change it toggle, i didn't complained it, then why you asking me

Comment: Agreed with Naila, @CarstenLøvboAndersen, you used something else in your code. You can see from the edit. `$(this).next(".help").show()` +1 Naila

Comment: all i changed when i edited was `show()` to `toogle()`

Answer (score 1):

You should not have the same ids attached to multiple elements. You can use **[next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** to select he next element after the button and **[slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)** to show/hide the div:

```js
$('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
   $(this).next('.help').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.help{
  display: none;
}
input[type='button']{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultTab">
  <input id="help_button_1" type="button" value="Full Info">
  <div id="help_1" class="help">Table with data</div>
  <input id="help_button_2" type="button" value="Full Info">
  <div id="help_2" class="help">Table with data</div>
  <input id="help_button_3" type="button" value="Full Info">
  <div id="help_3" class="help">Table with data</div>
</div>
```